# How to change default style of chart(graph) in magento?

Tags: charts, themes, magento-1.9

I want to change the default chart style. My default chart contains straight lines and I want the curved lines with dots on it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can anyone give answer to my question instead of editing my question please?

Comment: Your question has been marked as very low quality.  People editing the question are somewhat helping you. Perhaps you could add further information: detailed questions stimulate good answers.